# How do you rank up metal working skill?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I've recently started playing ESO and taken to blacksmithing as my primary profession. However, I can only currently make iron weapons/armour which give very little exp at lvl 2 blacksmithing and are quite weak in comparison to current equipment. I found and refined high metal ore but I am unable to make anything from it, saying, "You need metal working skill of lvl 2". Is metal working a separate skill that's levelled up passively in blacksmithing or is it a separate skill that I need to unlock? Furthermore, is there an efficient way to level up my blacksmithing at my current level without having to spend countless hours finding iron ore and smelting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metal Working is in fact a passive ability of that, Blacksmithing. It allows the use of Ingots as stated [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Metalworking). As for levelling, I've found it more efficient to create and de construct your newly constructed equipment. [This](http://eso-fashion.com/crafting-guide-blacksmithing/) may be a good place to start as a guideline.

Comment: Only partially true - in fact, deconstructing stuff crafted by you is essentially the most inefficient way to level crafting (assuming you'd have an unlimited amount of items from any source). Most efficient learning is "learning from others", i.e. find someone who wants to level black smithing as well, let them deconstruct your items and you deconstruct their items. This way you gain a lot more inspiration compared to salvaging your own crafted gear.

Comment: @Mario Yes, that's a valid point. I was doing it based solely alone before I convinced another person to play. Then, as you stated, we used each others equipment. My apologies for missing that on my answer.

Comment: @Mario from what I've noticed, deconstructing is mainly useful if the items are high enough level.  So what you said is true, but if your combat skill is high enough, items you find will be more than enough that you don't have to find someone to basically powerlevel your professions.

Comment: If I deconstruct another player's creation multiple times, will it slowly lose the amount of exp gain the more I deconstruct it?

Comment: @Thomas as your profession levels up, you will earn less exp.  So yes, you would lose exp gain over time.  Edit: i should clarify, you do not lose exp by deconstructing 1 player's items multiple times (unless they have changed that in the last several months).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question more directly, ESO limits the recipes based on the primary passive ability for each profession.  So for blacksmith, that would be your Metalworking skill.  You have to put skill points into it, and meet the level requirement to unlock the next tier recipes.

It's designed that way so you can't just automatically be good at every profession by making items, and limits what items you can make until you've put in enough time for it.

The best way to level up is a mix between 2 things.  1. Smelt ore into Ingots and make items (both don't give a lot of exp), and 2. deconstruct items you find.  #2 is much faster at leveling up depending on the item.  I think the rarer items give more exp, so blue would give more exp than green.  Also the higher items give more exp, but the downside is that you have to go out and find the items (meaning your combat skills need to be high enough).

So i would do a mix of both, when you are out looking for dungeons/loot, harvest the items you need (I.E. ore veins for blacksmithing).  Then focus on your daily crafting quests to make items to get a resource map.  Those maps will give you several nodes of resources, and give more than a normal node will.  It's worth doing, then any items you make or find, deconstruct for more exp.  I tend to sell things that have the sell for more gold trait, then scrap everything else.

It's still time consuming, but that should give you a good idea on what to do.  Also the daily crafting quests are on the billboard near the crafting stations.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you! In addition to my original question, in terms of the daily crafting requests, the scarcity of iron veins around davon's watch has made scouting a chore. I know they typically spawn around mountain/cliff bases but are there particular areas that spawn them more frequently? Do higher risk areas merit a higher frequency of veins, or is it randomized?

Comment: It's pretty random, but what you may notice over time is each node has specific spawn points it can spawn at.  Even though each area is randomized, it is better to find several areas to travel between if you can.  I don't know of any good areas, but caves/dungeon caves will have ore nodes, and along cliffs/mountains will too.  Risk is just going to be based on your combat level, because you will have to fight or run from mobs that you agro.  Logs are slightly harder than ore, and some of the most random are plants and enchanting materials (i forget their name).